# Inheriting classes from std::

Tags: c++, json, c++11

There are many similar questions and I found both pro and against reasons to use this pattern so I am asking this here:

I need to make a JSON implementation in C++ (let's say that it is sort of like a homework). I was thinking to do it like this:

```
namespace JSON {
  class JSON { };
  class object : public JSON, public std::unordered_map<std::string,JSON> { };
  class vector : public JSON, public std::vector<JSON> { };
  class string : public JSON, public std::string { };
  ...
};
```

If you think about it, it all make sense. The JSON object "is-an" unordered_map, the JSON vector "is-a" vector and so on. Just that they are also a JSON value and, for example, a JSON vector can contain any type of JSON values (objects, vectors, strings etc.). You get a lot of benefits too, you can then just use the JSON "naturally" in C++ (you can have an actual std::string vector inside json["mystringlist"], json being actually an unordered_map).

I am not really a C++ expert but is there any specific reason why not to do this?

Comment: you can't have a class using the same identifier as its enclosing namespace

Comment: First off: It's rarely a good idea to name a class the same as the namespace it resides in. That just calls for trouble. Secondly it might be a better idea to have has-a relationships and create a template class `JSON<T>` where `T` is the type you want to de-/serialize.

Comment: I think inheriting data structures is a bad idea. I've done it and regretted it. The access granted to the user can be problematic.

Comment: The name of the class and namespace are just examples. @πάνταῥεῖ, if I make it JSON<T>, then how do you read a JSON file? You would need to know in advance if you are expecting a JSON object or a JSON array and declare it properly.

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie You probably have to declare more than a single class to handle a JSON file ...

Comment: You can read about the [Circle-ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) that explains why a circle is not an ellipse. Similarly a JSON object is not an `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any specific reason why not to do this?

Yes. What you obtain with this, is UB. The problem arises from the `std::` containers not supporting polymorphism. They were not designed to be inherited from (no virtual destructor) and this means you cannot write a correct/safe destructor sequence.

Instead, your solution probably should look like this:

```
namespace XYZ { // <-- cannot have same name as class here
    class JSON { };
    class object : public JSON {
        std::unordered_map<std::string,JSON> values;
    public:
        JSON& operator[]( const std::string& key );
    };
    class vector : public JSON {
        // same here
    };
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

- I wouldn't recommend to inherit from STL.
- Due to performance reasons **STL standard containers do not have virtual destructors**, thus you cannot handle them polymorphically.
- This means that there's no way to use runtime polymorphisim and expect proper desctructors for them.
- Inheriting from STL, although is perfectly allowable, most of the times denotes bad design. I would recommend not following the **inherits from** way but rather **has a** way:

---

```
namespace JSON {
  class JSON { };
  class object : public JSON 
  { 
    std::unordered_map<std::string, JSON> m;

    public:
    // provide interface to access m.
    };
  class Vector : public JSON { 
    std::vector<JSON> v;

    public:
    // provide interface to access v.
  };
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're thinking that a JSON object is an unordered map, so it should inherit from `std::unordered_map`. I think you're making a logical jump here. A JSON object is definitely what you would describe as an example of an "unordered map", but is it really a `std::unordered_map`? I wouldn't say so. To say it's an `std::unordered_map` suggests that it should share the interface of `std::unordered_map` and should be able to be used anywhere that a `std::unordered_map` is used. I suggest that the interface of `std::unordered_map` is more complex and lower level than you'd want from a JSON object.

On top of this, for the most part the standard library classes are not designed to be used as base classes (especially not if they're then used polymorphically).

Considering these two points, I'd suggest that it makes much more sense for you to represent your JSON classes *in terms* of the standard library components, but not with an *is-a* relationship. Instead, use the standard library components as members of the JSON classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is actually better to wrap it within your own class (i.e. proxy using std as member) since it makes it much more loosely coupled and if you would like to use a different data structure it would be quite easy, since you could simply modify your own class while the std classes should not be modified at all. If the interface of your objects is simple, maybe you should even implement your own interface (to make it easily compatible when you want to use a different data structure from std or boost or whatever suits your needs). Your current implementation is maybe not the best one at mentioned in the comments, but i would still recommend wrapping std uses in your own class (especially in larger applications).