# unable to access base class function c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

Why does this code:

```
class myvector: public std::complex<float>{
            float x;
            float y;
            public:
            myvector(const float x_ = 0, const float y_ = 0) : std::complex::complex(x_), std::complex::complex(y_), x(x_), y(y_) {}
    };

int main(){
    myvector u, v;
    std::cout<< u + v;
}
```

Result in this error?

```
error: conversion from ‘std::complex<float>’ to non-`scalar type ‘myvector’ requested`
```

Shouldn't I have access to an overloaded + operator since I inherited std::complex that already has an overloaded + operator?

Comment: @user3191398 I could, but I thought the whole point of inheritance was to be able to use the functions of the base class. That's why I am a little confused

Comment: If the question if unclear could I at least know why? It makes sense to me when I read it

Comment: I guess, operators are declared out of class. Edit: sorry, I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by `std::complex::complex(x_), std::complex::complex(y_)`? Are you sure it compiles?

Comment: @xskxzr from the examples I have seen online, my understanding is that I need to call the constructor of the base class when constructing the derived class. So I am making 2 std::complex objects by calling the base constructor twice

Comment: You cannot "make" your class contain a base class more than once.

Comment: @xskxzr It's obvious that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the members `x` and `y` since these values are stored in the `std::complex` your class inherits from.

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

class myvector : public std::complex<float> {
public:
    myvector(const float x_ = 0, const float y_ = 0)
    : std::complex<float>{ x_, y_ }  // just call the base class constructor
    {}
};

int main()
{
    myvector u, v;
    std::cout << u + v;
}
```

[Thou shalt not inherit from classes that don't have a virtual destructor, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983937/inheriting-classes-from-std)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. Why do I need to call std::complex<float> in the member init list even though I inherited std::complex<float>? Why can't I do std::complex{x_, y_}?

Comment: You can also call `complex{ x_, y_ }` because `complex` is injected in your class.

Comment: Re: "Why can't I do std::complex{x_, y_}" -- because `std::complex` is a **template**; the name of an initializer has to be a **type**, in this case, `std::complex<float>`. Templates are patterns for creating types. In some circumstances you can use a template name as shorthand for a particular instance of that template, but in general, when you need a type, you can't just use the name of a template.

Comment: @Swordfish : Nothing wrong with inheriting from classes that don't have a virtual destructor providing you *never* new a derived class and assigned it to a pointer to base and then later call delete. If you do that, you do need a virtual base destructor otherwise, no you don't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler does not know how to apply `std::complex<float> operator+(const std::complex<float>&, const std::complex<float>&)` to your concrete class `myvector`. The direct fix is to write an overloaded operator+ for your class or an implicit conversion constructor:

```
class myvector : public std::complex<float> {
public:
    myvector(const float x_ = 0, const float y_ = 0)
    : std::complex<float>{ x_, y_ }  // just call the base class constructor
    {}

    myvector(const std::complex<float> &ref) : std::complex<float>(ref) {}
};
```

However, it looks like you are trying to extend functionality of the `std::complex` class by using inheritance, which is generally not a good idea because its destructor is not virtual. A better approach would be to make the `std::complex` a member of your `myvector` and provide your own public API.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Yes I am trying to extend the functionality of std::complex instead of using my own overloaded operators. What would be the solution in the event where I am unable to write my own overloaded+ and I am unable to use std::complex as a member of myvector? Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, you can add a free (global) function that could do it: `myvector operator+(const myvector& a, const myvector& b) { return myvector(a.real() + b.real(), a.imag() + b.imag()); }`

Comment: Thank you! So there’s no way for me to use the operator+ provided in std::complex directly? I need to wrap it with my own operator+ correct?

Comment: I don't believe so, not without modifying the `myvector` class code.

Comment: I can modify the code for myvector class, just that it must inherit std::complex. Other than that I’m free to do what I want

Comment: I edited my answer with some code that should get you headed in the direction you want.