# c++ how to access STL complex + binary operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Hello I have trouble access STL complex + binary operator, my fVector is derived from std::complex, I try to call the std::complex binary + operator function to do the calculation, but I say it does have member of operator +.

ok update more of my code as request, there is 3 file which is  fVector2D_test.cpp  fVector2D.cpp and  fVector2D.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include "fVector2D.hpp"
//using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
  /*fVector2D   u, v(2.4f, 7), w(v); 
  cout << v.X(); u = fVector2D(u.X(), v.Y()); 
   cout << u <<endl;
  // v.Y() = 3.4f; // compiler error 
  fVector2D a(1, 2), b(2, 3); 
  float dot = a*b; 
  cout << dot <<endl;
  cout << fVector2D::EX << "+" << fVector2D::EY;*/ 

  fVector2D v(3,4.1f), u(1.2f,8.5f);
  fVector2D w = u + v;
  cout << w << endl;  
  //w = exp(std::complex<float>(0,0.2f))*v;
  //cout << w << endl;
 // cout << (u*v) << endl;
  //cout << fVector2D::EX << endl;
  //cout << fVector2D::EY << endl;
  //cout << abs(v) << endl;
  return 0;
}

#include <complex>

class fVector2D : public std::complex<float>
{ 
public: 
  fVector2D(float x=0, float y =0);
  fVector2D(const fVector2D& floatVector2D);
  float X()const;
  float Y()const;
  //static const EX;
  //static const EY;
private:

}; 

fVector2D operator+(const fVector2D& , const fVector2D&); 

#include "fVector2D.hpp"

fVector2D::fVector2D(float x, float y)
: std::complex<float>(x, y)
{

}

fVector2D::fVector2D(const fVector2D& floatVector2D)
: std::complex<float>(floatVector2D)
{

}

float fVector2D::X()const
{
  return real();
}

float fVector2D::Y()const
{
  return imag();
}


fVector2D operator+(const fVector2D& lhs, const fVector2D& rhs)
{
 return std::complex<float>::operator+(lhs,rhs);// compile error , no operator + in the member
}
```

Comment: please paste minimal  example that shows your problem

Comment: ok done the update

Comment: That's far from minimal and complete and further badly formatted. Do you want people to read that?

Comment: `return ((const std::complex<float> &) lhs) + ((const std::complex<float> &)rhs)` will do it.   Or, more explicitly, `return static_cast<const std::complex<float> &>( lhs) + static_cast<const std::complex<float> &>(rhs)`.  This will allow the compiler to work out what `operator+()` to call, regardless of whether it is a member or non-member.       Of course, deriving from `std::complex<float>` is a pretty poor idea to start with, but I'll leave that alone.

Comment: a [mcve] means that we can take the code you posted, and without any changes, compile the code and see the results.  Also "minimal" meaning the least code that reproduces the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983937/inheriting-classes-from-std

Comment: ok I add in all my code that require run the test
@peter it does not work ,

Comment: It's still not minimal. You need to extract a MCVE from your code. Neither fragments nor the whole code qualify as MCVE. Please read the links you were given!

Comment: You also need to provide a conversion constructor that converts a `std::complex<float>` to an `fVector2D`.   Otherwise, there is no way to convert the result of adding two `complex<float>` into a `fVector2D`.

Comment: @peter 

peter is right, I make a coneverison constructor of std::complex<float> and it solve the problem

Comment: Implement your vector from scratch instead, it will give you fewer headaches and more type safety.

Answer (score 0):

[+ for complex numbers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3) is a free function, not a member function. That is why you can not access it using `complex<float>::` syntax.

Beside this problem your code has other problems(I have trouble seeing any real scenario where one would want to inherit from std::complex), but that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: the given task is to derived from  std::complex<float> as base, is mainly use for grid coordinate

Comment: `operator+` for `complex` is a "non-member function", not a "free function".